# How to reveal a presenterwidget/presenter in it's parent only on some event in gwt platform?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I'm doing an application in GWT-Platform. I've layouted my main page using dock layout. In the west part of the dock layout I'll be having some links (`Anchor`). Based on what I'm clicking I have to display a `PresenterWidget`/ `presenter`  in the center.

How can I achieve this? i've tried like this with presenter

```
@UiHandler("myAnchor")
public void onClicked(ClickEvent event) {
    mainContent.clear();
    mainContent.add(newPageinCenter);
}
```

in the Parent presenter view i have used `SimpleLayoutPanel` for center of dock

```
<g:center>
<g:SimpleLayoutPanel ui:field="mainContent">        
</g:SimpleLayoutPanel>
</g:center>
```

and in the child again i'm using a docklayout panel to add some more custom widgets to it's 
sides like

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel>
    <g:north size='60' unit='EM'>
        <g:SimpleLayoutPanel>
            <widgets:CustWid1 ui:field="policySelPane" />
        </g:SimpleLayoutPanel>
    </g:north>
    <g:center>
        <g:VerticalSplitPanel>
            <widgets:CustWid2 ui:field="createPolicyPane" />
            <widgets:CustWid3 ui:field="stackPane" />
        </g:VerticalSplitPanel>
    </g:center>
    <g:south size='60'>
        <g:FlowPanel>
            <g:Button ui:field="computePremium">Compute Premium</g:Button>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:south>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

but i'm able to seen only north and i'm using `RevealRootLayoutContentEvent` in my child `Presenter` also what is my mistake

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what?

Comment: hi Anders that is working with some flaw,I'm not getting view completely, let me edit the question to share my code, the error is because of some mistake in gin configuration.